# .net HttpClient does not complete

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, async-await, httpclient

A simple vb.net code block which calls an api for a token. However the HttpClient.GetAsync() does not complete. I created a brand new project and it works just fine. But with the current project I cannot figure out what is the cause.

```
Private Async Function GetTokenAsync() As Task

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) Or String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) Then
        Throw New InvalidParameterException("Missing Username and/or Password")
    End If

    Dim url As String = tokenApiUrl &
        "?username=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(userName) &
        "&password=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(password)

    Dim client As New HttpClient()

    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync(url)  ' <--- goes silent

    If response.StatusCode.ToString() = "401" Then
        Throw New UnauthorizedAccessException()
    End If

    token = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

End Function
```

Comment: When you call client.GetAsync(...) does it eventually return a timeout error?  Have you tried making the same requests in tools like Postman?

Comment: @Hursey no timeout returned. I can make the call simply using browser to get a correct response.